# What is the haskell way to copy a directory

Tags: haskell

I find myself doing more and more scripting in haskell. But there are some cases where I'm really not sure of how to do it "right".
e.g. copy a directory recursively (a la unix `cp -r`).

Since I mostly use linux and Mac Os I usually cheat:

```
import System.Cmd
import System.Exit

copyDir ::  FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ExitCode
copyDir src dest = system $ "cp -r " ++ src ++ " " ++ dest
```

But what is the recommended way to copy a directory in a platform independent fashion?
I didn't find anything suitable on hackage.

This is my rather naiv implementation I use so far:

```
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath((</>))
import Control.Applicative((<$>))
import Control.Exception(throw)
import Control.Monad(when,forM_)

copyDir ::  FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
copyDir src dst = do
  whenM (not <$> doesDirectoryExist src) $
    throw (userError "source does not exist")
  whenM (doesFileOrDirectoryExist dst) $
    throw (userError "destination already exists")

  createDirectory dst
  content <- getDirectoryContents src
  let xs = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) content
  forM_ xs $ \name -> do
    let srcPath = src </> name
    let dstPath = dst </> name
    isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist srcPath
    if isDirectory
      then copyDir srcPath dstPath
      else copyFile srcPath dstPath

  where
    doesFileOrDirectoryExist x = orM [doesDirectoryExist x, doesFileExist x]
    orM xs = or <$> sequence xs
    whenM s r = s >>= flip when r
```

Any suggestions of what really is the way to do it?

---

I updated this with the suggestions of hammar and FUZxxl.
...but still it feels kind of clumsy to me for such a common task!

Comment: If no such standard library exists, why not making one? ;)

Comment: I think this doesn't handle symlinks properly. It should recreate them. See System.Posix.Files.

Comment: The code does not work if src and dst are not disjoint. `copyDir "A" "A/B"` will loop infinitely.  See also https://github.com/yesodweb/Shelly.hs/issues/154

Comment: Note that **this does not copy the metadata!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that does this on Hackage.

Your code looks pretty good to me. Some comments:

1. > ```
   > dstExists <- doesDirectoryExist dst
   > ```

   This does not take into account that a *file* with the destination name might exist.
2. > ```
   > if or [not srcExists, dstExists] then print "cannot copy"
   > ```

   You might want to throw an exception or return a status instead of printing directly from this function.
3. > ```
   > paths <- forM xs $ \name -> do
   >     [...]
   >   return ()
   > ```

   Since you're not using `paths` for anything, you can change this to

   ```
   forM_ xs $ \name -> do
     [...]
   ```

Comment: You might also consider writing `if not srcExists || dstExists then print "cannot copy"`

Comment: hammar and @FUXxxl: thanks for your suggestions. I updated the code! ...wish this would be packaged in some neat library.

Comment: @oliver: The `return ()` at the end is now redundant.

Comment: @oliver: Also `error` is generally used for things that should be considered programming errors, such as calling `head` on an empty list. For IO related errors an IO exception should be used instead. See: [Error vs. Exception](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Error_vs._Exception).

Comment: @hammar: thanks for your insights...the article you cite was interesting. I updated my version with this...not sure if this is the correct way to us a `userError` here ... but it is catchable. This was the only way I know of how to throw an IOException.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to use the [`Shelly`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly) library in order to do this, see [`cp_r`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly-1.4.4/docs/Shelly.html#v:cp_r):

```
cp_r "sourcedir" "targetdir"
```

Shelly first tries to use native `cp -r` if available. If not, it falls back to a native Haskell `IO` implementation.

For further details on type semantics of `cp_r`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21715782/2597135) written by me to described how to use `cp_r` with `String` and or `Text`.

Shelly is not platform independent, since it relies on the [Unix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix) package, which is not supported under Windows.

Comment: As of today, Shelly's cp_r is buggy.`cp_r "A" "A/B"` loops see, https://github.com/yesodweb/Shelly.hs/issues/154

Comment: @andreas.abel Thanks for the notice. As I've answered on GitHub, I don't think it's really broken, except in a very special corner case that results in an error mesage using native `cp -r`. I think it should be fixed in Shelly, but even if it isn't fixed I think this is still the most pragmatic solution to the original question for most users.

Answer (score 2):

The [`filesystem-trees`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filesystem-trees/docs/System-File-Tree.html) package provides the means for a very simple implementation:

```
import System.File.Tree (getDirectory, copyTo_)

copyDirectory :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
copyDirectory source target = getDirectory source >>= copyTo_ target
```

Comment: Great. But looking today (Aug 2017), the last commit on this package is from 2015, and the hackage build matrix is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The [`MissingH`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH) package provides recursive directory traversals, which you might be able to use to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the function in Path.IO `copyDirRecur` with variants to include/exclude symlinks may be a newer and maintained solution. It requires to convert the filepath to `Path x Dir` which is achieved with `parseRelDir` respective `parseAbsDir`, but I think to have a more precise date type than `FilePath` is worthwile to avoid hard to track errors at run-time.

Comment: `path` and `path-io` are definitely a very good option to consider before rolling your own. Mind that `copyDirRecur` does not behave *exactly* like `cp -r`.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some functions for copying files and directories in the core Haskell library Cabal modules, specifically Distribution.Simple.Utils in package Cabal. [copyDirectoryRecursive](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/Cabal-2.4.0.1/Distribution-Simple-Utils.html#v:copyDirectoryRecursive) is one, and there are other functions near this one in that module.