# Shelly: Convert String to Shelly FilePath

Tags: haskell, shelly

I need to execute the [`cp_r`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly-1.4.4/docs/Shelly.html#v%3acp_r) function from the [Shelly](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly) library to copy `a` to `b`.

However,

```haskell
import Shelly
main = do cp_r "a" "b"
```

yields

```
Couldn't match expected type `Shelly.FilePath'
            with actual type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `cp_r', namely `"a"'
In the expression: cp_r "a" "b"
In an equation for `it': it = cp_r "a" "b"
```

for both the first and the second argument to `cp_r`.

How can I use `String` ([`FilePath`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.1.0.2/docs/System-FilePath-Windows.html#t%3aFilePath) is defined as String on any platform I know of) as argument to `cp_r`?

*Note:* This question intentionally does not show any research effort as it was answered Q&A-Style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a detailed and official description, see the [convert between Text and FilePath](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly-1.4.4/docs/Shelly.html#g:13) section on Hackage.

Let's first see how to do it with [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text):

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Shelly

cp_r (fromText "a") (fromText "b")
```

From here on, we can just use [`Text.pack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v%3apack) to apply this method to strings

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Shelly
import Data.Text

cp_r (fromText $ pack "a") (fromText $ pack "b")
```

Note that in case you also need to use the `FilePath` from `Prelude` in a module, you need to use

```haskell
import Shelly hiding (FilePath)
```

to avoid conflicts (alternatively, you could use `Prelude.FilePath` and `Shelly.FilePath`).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Uli Kohler - here is an example of such usage:

https://github.com/haroldcarr/make-mp3-copies/blob/master/MakeMP3Copies.hs