# `mapM_`, `copyFile`, and a ghost file

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm having a strange problem when copying a list of files in Haskell. If I run the following code:

```
copy :: [FilePath] -> FilePath -> IO ()
-- Precondition: dir must be a directory.
copy fs dir = do
    isDir <- doesDirectoryExist dir
    if (isDir)
    then do
        mapM_ putStrLn fs -- Poor man's debug.
        mapM_  (`copyFile` dir) fs
    else ioError (userError $ dir ++ " is not a directory.")
```

The output of `mapM_ putStrLn fs` gives a single file, which extists, however the second `mapM_` fails with the following message:

```
./.copyFile4363.tmp: copyFile: inappropriate type (Is a directory)
```

I'm really puzzled, since in both uses of `mapM_` the list `fs` is passed as parameter.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [System.Directory Haddock](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/directory-1.2.2.0/System-Directory.html#g:3)  (emphasis mine):

> ```
> copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO () Source
> ```
>
> `copyFile old new` copies the existing file from *old* to *new*. If the *new* file already exists, it is atomically replaced by the *old* file. **Neither path may refer to an existing directory**. The permissions of *old* are copied to *new*, if possible.

Comment: Indeed! I overlooked that piece of documentation. I cannot find a bash `cp` equivalent in Haskell :(

Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807025/what-is-the-haskell-way-to-copy-a-directory

Comment: @DamianNadales For shell stuff, I keep seeing more and more people referring to the [turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) library. It has a [`cp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.2.2/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:cp) function, but I couldn't see from the docs whether it supports a directory target.

Comment: I think it doesn't since `cp` uses the `Filesystem` implementation of `copyFile`. However turtle is a good starting point for start adding functionality.